# Correlation between rows in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows, correlation

I have this dataframe. I would like to find a way to make a correlation matrix between an Hour and the same hour of the day before (for example H01 of 28/09 vs H01 of 27/09).

I thought about two different approaches:
1) Do the corr matrix of the transpose dataframe.

```
    dft=df.transpose()
    dft.corr()
```

2) create a copy of the dataframe with 1 day/rows of lag and than do `.corrwith()` in order to compare them.
In the first approach I obtain weird results (for example rows like 634 and 635 low correlated even if they have values very similar), in the second approach I obtain all ones. I'm ideally looking forward to find the correlation in days close to eachothers actually. Send help please

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at [rolling apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.apply.html)? Just as an idea

Comment: Approach 1 is correct. The reason for the low correlation of row 634 and 635 is that row 634 is almost constant.